How to convert recursive PostgreSQL request to function
I have write PostgreSQL query what working perfectly:

I try to convert this query to function
 DROP FUNCTION path1(character varying,character varying);
 CREATE
 OR REPLACE FUNCTION path1(enter character varying, request character varying) RETURNS TABLE (
   reti INTEGER,
   retid character varying,
   retname character varying,
   retmime character varying,
   retpath character varying
 ) AS $$
 BEGIN
   WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
     SELECT i, parent, id, name, type, '' AS path
     FROM entry 
     WHERE name = enter
     UNION ALL
     SELECT e.i, e.parent, e.id, e.name, e.type, (x.path || '/' ||      e.name) AS path
     FROM entry e, x 
     WHERE x.id = e.parent
   )
   SELECT x.i as reti, x.id as retid, x.name as retname, types.mime as retmime, x.path as retpath
   FROM x 
   JOIN types ON types.i = x.type
   WHERE x.path = request;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

 GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION  path1(enter character varying, request character varying) TO public;

and call it
 select  * from  public.PATH1 ('JS-VBNET-2', '/Index.htm');

But I get trouble
 ERROR:  42601: query has no destination for result data
 HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
 CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function path1(character varying,character varying) line 3 at SQL statement

AI hint is:
Add a destination for the result data, such as using INTO or returning the results in a SELECT statement.

What going wrong? How I can convert my function correctly?

You need to be careful with terms, a Procedure is a different thing then a Function. Also an SQL procedure/function is different then what you are using which is plpgsql. Edit the question to get your terms correct.

Thanks @AdrianKlaver. Is this question correct now? But this term not solve my problem. I can not convert query to Function and can not upload Function to Supabase, because Table is absent as parameters in Supabase uploading function panel.

I don't use Supabase so I can't check my self. The YT video here Supabase Functions shows creation of functions directly in the SQL editor. Might take a look and see if that would work.

Thanks, @AdrianKlaver. It's critical advice that SQL editor doing the same that dedicated Supabase form

I don't understand what that means?

@AdrianKlaver, you are right, there is no matter how function is creating in Supabase, with SQL editor or with special form. Yes, I can create function just in command line, and I can see this function remotely. And my query working fine on this data and this request parameters. But when I wrap query as Function - query stop working, something going wrong exactly in my wrapper query to function. Therefore my old question with two part was modified, because yes, you are right function can created in SQL editor, but something going wrong when I wrap workable query to Function.

So, firstly, Supabase SQL editor allow create function, don't need to use special form "New Function" in Supabase. Function visible in Supabase locally and remotelly:

And secondary, after some experiment I understand troubles. Correct workable functions is
 DROP FUNCTION path1(character varying,character varying);
 CREATE
 OR REPLACE FUNCTION path1 (
   enter CHARACTER VARYING,
   request CHARACTER VARYING
 ) RETURNS TABLE (
   reti INTEGER,
   retid CHARACTER VARYING,
   retname CHARACTER VARYING,
   retmime CHARACTER VARYING,
   retpath text
 ) AS $$
 BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
     SELECT i, parent, id, name, type, '' AS path
     FROM entry 
     WHERE name = enter
     UNION ALL
     SELECT e.i, e.parent, e.id, e.name, e.type, (x.path || '/' || e.name)      AS path
FROM entry e, x 
WHERE x.id = e.parent
   )
   SELECT x.i AS reti, x.id AS retid, x.name AS retname, types.mime AS retmime, x.path AS retpath
   FROM x 
   JOIN types ON types.i = x.type
   WHERE x.path = request;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
 GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION  path1(enter character varying, request character varying) TO public;

Key feature of changing is strange, when PostgreSQL combined character varying fields - result is "text", not character varying.
and strange response was because I miss "Return Query" before CTE definition


Postgres uses text as the native string type per Character Types: ... text is PostgreSQL's native string data type, in that most built-in functions operating on strings are declared to take or return text not character varying. For many purposes, character varying acts as though it were a domain over text . So select pg_typeof('' || 'test'); text.



RETURNS TABLE is same as RETURNS SETOF. See plpgsql returns 41.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY

